# Unable to add product in cart with custom option via querystring

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, custom-options, addtocart

I am trying to add products with custom options in cart via query string but it does not worked.

```
//my redirecting on click here
<?php echo "http://localhost/magento_bnsb_guide/index.php/checkout/cart/add/product/".$_product->getId()."?qty=2&options[3]=1"; ?>')">
```

---

i copied this url from source.

---

`http://localhost/magento_bnsb_guide/index.php/checkout/cart/add/product/7?qty=2&options[3]=1`

Comment: how or where to get form key?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Magento version greater 1.7.x.x you need to add form key with URL

```
http://localhost/magento_bnsb_guide/index.php/checkout/cart/add/product/7/form_key/wUCWIqJMKYAh1lg9?qty=2&options[3]=1
```

Comment: i am using 1.9 version

Comment: how or where to get form key?

Comment: I am using form_key but its also not working url is given below genrated after using form_key___________

http://localhost/magento_bnsb_guide/index.php/checkout/cart/add/product/7form_key/jB0YB2KjpDkttiA2?qty=2&options[3]=1

Comment: you missed slash '/' before form_key parameter in your URL

Comment: great its worked but it shows an warning "Some of the selected item options are not currently available."

Comment: can you help me in telling how to do this query string request using ajax?

Comment: there are few ready made free extension available for Magento. like Ajax Add to cart

Comment: yes they are available for just simple products not with custom option. i am showing custom option myself. showi have to do it manually

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :)

Comment: @rahulchaurasia: Mage Store Extension supports Options in popup too https://www.magestore.com/magento-ajax-cart-extension.html

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `uenc` or security code to go with that. Try using

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct());
echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);
```

Comment: how to attach query string with it

Comment: How would you add a simple product (size option of configurable product)? - same as selecting a T-shirt in size SMALL on the product page ... but then for getAddUrl? thx